# Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) in Angular RC 5 when unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I just upgraded to Angular RC 5 and now all component that uses 'ROUTER_DIRECTIVES' fails with 'Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' when I try to unit test the component.

```
import { inject, addProviders } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ComponentFixture, TestComponentBuilder } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';

describe('Component: Home', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([HomeComponent, UserService, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router]);
  });  

  it('should inject the component', inject([HomeComponent, UserService, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router],
    (component: HomeComponent) => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      // expect(component.currentUser.firstname).toEqual('Jan');
    }));
```

The full error log:

```
     Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 10 0.0.0)
   Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
       at new BaseException (webpack:///C:/ng/anbud/~/@angular/compiler/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:0 <- src/test.ts:2943:23)
       at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (webpack:///C:/ng/anbud/~/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:551:0 <- src/test.ts:24542:19)
       at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (webpack:///C:/ng/anbud/~/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:448:0 <- src/test.ts:24439:26)
       at webpack:///C:/ng/anbud/~/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:594:0 <- src/test.ts:24585:41
       at Array.forEach (native)
       at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (webpack:///C:/ng/anbud/~/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:575:0 <- src/test.ts:24566:19)
       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (webpack:///C:/ng/anbud/~/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:305:0 <- src/test.ts:24296:58)
       at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (webpack:///C:/ng/anbud/~/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:150:0 <- src/test.ts:37986:47)
       at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (webpack:///C:/ng/anbud/~/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:78:0 <- src/test.ts:37914:37)
       at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (webpack:///C:/ng/anbud/~/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:52:0 <- src/test.ts:37888:21)
```

Any ideas how to unit test components with routing?

Comment: I guess you need something like https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/951ecb4d9024b6b67a326ef2f04eb58a5190f219/modules/%40angular/router/test/integration.spec.ts#L24

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Was finally able to fix it, and it was as simple as this:

```
beforeEach(() => addProviders([
    { 
        provide: Router, 
        useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); }
    }]));
```

Comment: From here you can use jasmine for testing.
`expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/success']);`

Comment: In 2.0.0 this also works when adding it to the providers section of an NgModule:
`providers: [
        {
          provide: Router,
          useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); }
        }]`

Comment: Please update your answer, it's very out of date. [`RouterTestingModule`](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule) is the official way to do this now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49407245/6017500 works for latest version of Angular 7

Answer (score 50):

for me it worked to add the RouterTestingModule

```
  import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ HomeComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Answer (score 28):

In my case, I had Router in providers and RouterTestingModule in imports. Guess this was causing a conflict. The following configuration worked:

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [Component],
        imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,             
        ],
        providers: [
         ...         //Remove Router from providers
        ]              

    });
```

Answer (score 24):

I did not have any luck with the above solutions. Instead, I followed the recommended approach in the official documentation: [Testing Routed Components](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#routed-components)

First, create a stubbed router with whatever methods your component calls:

```
class RouterStub {
  navigateByUrl(url: string) {
    return url;
  }
}
```

Then, when configuring your testing module you do the following:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  providers: [
    {provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub}
  ]
});
```

Comment: This is the right answer for me. I just put {provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub} into the "providers" array, and also put the above-mentioned "class RouterStub" (the whole thing, with the body) directly into my spec.ts file, and the error was fixed. The other answers didn't work for me.

Answer (score 11):

Try adding RouterModule:

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                 ...
                {provide: Router, useClass: RouterModule},
        });
    });
```

Comment: For some components, using this method resulted in an error "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Router ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule DynamicTestModule in ./DynamicTestModule@-1:-1"? However, using @masterwok's method worked.

Answer (score 9):

I just had to **remove the router from the providers**. That was causing the problem for me.

Comment: This was it. Thanks a million

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error, importing RouterTestModule in my imports array, and removing Router/ActivatedRoute from providers and also removing RouterModule from my imports array helped me to get over this issue.

This is how my working version looks like

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyAppComponent } from './my-apppp.component';
import { MyAppService } from '../../../services/my-app.service';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyAppComponent ],
      schemas:      [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [ FormsModule, RouterTestingModule ],
      providers: [ MyAppService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

I know a lot of people already commented in here, but I felt like providing a updated answer would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For latest Angular 7, here is the solution that worked for me.
The example is copied from [latest angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#routing-component).

**app/dashboard/dashboard.component.spec.ts (spies)**

```
const routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigateByUrl']);
const heroServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HeroService', ['getHeroes']);

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HeroService, useValue: heroServiceSpy },
    { provide: Router,      useValue: routerSpy }
  ]
})
```

**app/dashboard/dashboard.component.spec.ts (navigate test)**

```
it('should tell ROUTER to navigate when hero clicked', () => {

  heroClick(); // trigger click on first inner <div class="hero">

  // args passed to router.navigateByUrl() spy
  const spy = router.navigateByUrl as jasmine.Spy;
  const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];

  // expecting to navigate to id of the component's first hero
  const id = comp.heroes[0].id;
  expect(navArgs).toBe('/heroes/' + id,
    'should nav to HeroDetail for first hero');
});
```