# How to unit test router in Angular2 RC5?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

Below is my AppComponent code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  template: `<h1>Angular 2 app</h1>
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
    <a [routerLink] = "['/login']">sign in</a>
    <div class="outer-outlet">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

I tried to find in google but I only found router testing in lower angular version <5.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to unit test in the above given the limited amount of code you shared, but I'd recommend taking a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39015918/810794) for how to properly import the Router for unit testing, specifically Gunter's comment on the original question.