# (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for Router in Angular 2.1.2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am upgrading from RC4 to 2.1.2. I understand that ROUTER_DIRECTIVES is deprecated. So in my LoginComponent now looks like this

```
import {Component,Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'app/login/auth.login.html',
  styleUrls:  ['app/login/auth.login.css'],
  providers: [FormBuilder, AuthService, { provide: Router, useClass: RouterModule} ]
})
@Injectable()
export class LoginComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, 
              private authSvc: AuthService, 
              private router: Router
              ) {....}
```

In app.routing.module.ts I have

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [ AuthGuard,  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then I am getting error as follows

```
zone.js@0.6.26?main=browser:232 Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).(…)
```

I have tried moved `{ provide: Router, useClass: RouterModule}` to app.routing.module.ts but it didn't help.

In RC4 we used `directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]` in root component and everything is taken care of. How do I use RouterModule to make Router resolved by the compiler?

Comment: After you **remove** `{ provide: Router, useClass: RouterModule} ` it should work, given you added the `AppRoutingModule` to the app module imports. Other than that, please try and provide a Plunker for better help.

Comment: I started without `{ provide: Router, useClass: RouterModule}` and got the error. Then I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015918/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-router-in-angular-rc-5-w and began adding `{ provide: Router, useClass: RouterModule}` but it didn't help either. So by removing `{ provide: Router, useClass: RouterModule}` I would still be getting the error. It must be something else I may have missed?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out so I can down vote it :-) That is not a solution. You need to have a little better understanding of DI to realize that is a dufus idea. Like I said, it should work once you import the AppRoutingModule into the app module. Can you provide a Plunker that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I think you are right. I removed it and the error went away. thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` in AppModule and `RouterModule` in other modules using Router. Don't put into component's providers, `AppRoutingModule` also seems unnecessary.